# C++ Pass by reference a single element array - It's factible?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Quick question about passing vars by reference: What's more appropiate:

1) Using the classic pointers syntax:

```
void change(int *a) { a = 0; }
...
int number = 1;
change(&number);
```

2) Or making it a single element array and passing it by reference as default:

```
void change(int a[]) { a[0] = 0; }
...
int number[1] = {1};
change(number);
```

Something I thought off. Wanted to know how's the difference in resource use if using an array of one element instead of a simple variable.

Comment: How about `void change(int& a) { a=0;} int number =1; change(number);`?

Comment: How is `int number = 1;` a single array element?  (well - technically any variable can be treated as a 1-element array but I don't think that's what you meant)

Comment: Google C++ style guideline prefers the classic one: void change(int *a) { *a = 0; }. Basically it recommends all non-const inputs to use pointer and all const inputs to be const reference.

Comment: @user3528438 the google style guide is for google to use and by no means represent industry idioms or best practices. They don't allow references... nuff' said.

Comment: `void change(int a[])` is *exactly the same as* `void change(int a*)`

Comment: @Tony Jiang Oh, I didn't know I could use the `&` operator that way. Thank you (and everyone ^.^). But yeah, I like how this looks instead of the chunk I wrote.

Comment: @LeoAM In this case `&` is not an operator. It means that the type is a reference. C++ has a problem with using the same symbols for different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point in making it a one element array. Just pass it in as a reference using the `&` operator. By making it a one element array you are making your code more complex, obfuscating the real purpose of the variable, and making the next developer's life much more annoying.

As for your resource use concerns, there is no resource different whatsoever. Under the hood both of them are basically just a pointer.

Answer (score 8):

The first one won't change the value `a` points to, it just makes a **copy** of `a` point to `NULL` and then immediately discards it.

If you want to pass by reference, just pass by reference:

```
void change(int& a) { a = 0; }

//...
int a;
change(a);
```

Comment: In general, pointers are more explicit than references for mutable arguments. Many style guides discourage non-const references (e.g. http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html)

Comment: @grep maybe for C-programmers. What else would you use a non-`const` reference for? And please, don't take the google style guide for granted, unless you work for google. "Many style guides discourage non-const references" - I dare you to show me 2 more, other than google's.

Comment: @grep The google guidelines are a bit of a joke. Follow if you don't know C++ and don't want to learn.

Comment: @grep seriously now, I tell you this with the best of intentions - don't follow the google style guide ad litteram.

Comment: Well, Google C++ style is somewhat restricted (mostly because of deliberate abstention from exceptions).
Stroustrup:
http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#call-by-reference
"My personal style is to use a pointer when I want to modify an object because in some contexts that makes it easier to spot that a modification is possible."
Sutter has a different opinion:
http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0321113586/items/sutter_item25.pdf
"Prefer passing by reference if the argument is required and the function won’t store a pointer to it or otherwise affect its ownership."

Answer (score 6):

Neither. C++ has references for this.

```
void change(int& a) { a = 0; }
```